# post video to youtube in app iphone

Tags: iphone, ios6, youtube-api

I am developing an app in which there is a requirement under which there is upload video of iPhone photo album to YouTube in app. I am searching on Google but can't succeeded. How can I solve this?

Comment: what have you searched ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check [this API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Uploading_Videos.)

hope it helps